# Error handling problem with Nodejs and Express

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I'm trying to handle errors produced in a Nodejs with Express app. I'm following [Express error-handling guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) but the errors didn't catched, and nothing appears on console and browser simply show Cannot GET /abc when request the incorrect url http://localhost:3000/abc

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const config = require("./config.js");


function logErrors (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack)
    next(err)
}

function errorHandler (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500)
    res.render("error", { error: err })
}

app.all("/", function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});


app.get("/favicon.ico", (req, res) => res.status(204));
app.use(express.static("public"))
app.use("/zips/:idReq", express.static("zips"))

const generateZip = require("./generateZip")
const fmeForm = require("./fmeForm")

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.send("Hello World !")
})

app.use("/generateZip", generateZip)
app.use("/downloadForm", fmeForm)


app.use(logErrors)
app.use(errorHandler)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`${config.nameServer} App listening on port ${port}`))
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a common route handler to invoke error handling method at last

```
app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
    // Either invoke error handler method by raising new error
    next(new Error('page not found'));

    // Or simply return the response
    res.status(404).send('page not found')
})
```